# Speed, rate, pace, tempo: what's the difference?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, word-usage

I looked up these three words in Oxford Dictionary and I found that they seem to be interchangeable in some cases.

Here's the question: what's the difference between the three words?

> *Rate:* [countable] a measurement of the speed at which something happens.

Most people walk at an average *rate* of 5 kilometres an hour. At the *rate* you work, you'll never finish!

> *Pace:* [singular, uncountable] the speed at which something happens.

It is difficult to keep up with the rapid *pace* of change. We encourage all students to work at their own *pace* (= as fast or as slow as they can).

> *Speed*: 1 [countable, uncountable] the rate at which somebody/something moves or travels.

He reduced *speed* and turned sharp left.

> *Speed* 2  [countable, uncountable] the rate at which something happens or is done.

This course is designed so that students can progress at their own *speed*.

> *Speed*: 3. [uncountable] the quality of being quick or rapid

The train began to pick up *speed* (= go faster). Increasing your walking *speed* will help to exercise your heart.

The accident was due to excessive *speed*. *Speed* is his greatest asset as a tennis player.

> *Tempo*: the speed of any movement or activity

the increasing tempo of life in Western society

Don’t let the other team dictate the tempo of the game

Comment: Very roughly, "speed" is the distance traveled per unit time, while "pace" is the number of operations (which may be, eg, footsteps) that occur per unit time.  "Rate" is kind of like speed, only measuring some other quantity (eg, liters volume) per unit time.  But all three tend to be used very loosely and often interchangeably, and each may be used with different (and likely more precise) definitions in certain industries or occupations.

Comment: See also "cadence"

Comment: Be aware that rate is also used to indicate prevalence in a population.  This is a misnomer but well established.  When you see that the annual murder rate someplace is 19.2, you might be tempted to think that means an average of 19.2 people are killed there each year, but it really means that for every 100,000 residents, 19.2 are homicide victims.

Comment: @deadrat thanks, but now I'm completely baffled by the fact that the murder rate of the town I used to live in was 1 in 7 years and it was considered high for the area.

Comment: @MattSamuel The murder rate is usually stated for a year.  So let's say your town has 5,000 people.  For the year in which the murder occurred, your town's murder rate is 20 per 100,000.  In 2014, the murder rate in Chicago was 14.8, but there are a lot more people in Chicago, about 2.7M, so there were a lot more homicides in Chicago, but the "rate" was lower because your town is so small.

Comment: @deadrat thanks, I understood that part (I'm actually a mathematician) it was the 1 that bothered me when the town had 13000 people. I must be remembering incorrectly (I saw this figure 11 years ago).

Comment: @MattSamuel Good Lord! I'm explaining simple ratios to an algebraic combinatorialist with a specialization in Schubert calculus.  Is my face red!  Sorry about that.  The 1 murder gives your town a murder rate on the order of Los Angeles', but why does it bother you?  An anomalous occurrence in a such a small place just gives you a misleading statistic.  Let me put it this way:  your town is more dangerous than Los Angeles the same sense the equivariant cohomology ring is more fundamental than the cohomology ring.  At least I think so.

Comment: @deadrat no worries. If it's a quoted rate per 100000 as you said, then less than one person would have been killed, but it probably was not a rate in that sense, it was the actual number killed (especially since it was an integer). I do remember thinking at the time that it was funny especially since if you just go over the river there's a city that, besides the university area, is pretty much a hellhole, and there were robberies and rapes reported frequently.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm sorry, I misread your comment to say that there was 1 murder in your town that year.  Yeah, I agree.  The "1" probably wasn't the so-called rate, just a singular shocking event in a small town.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 4 words above-mentioned are sometimes used interchangeably, but there are some clear distinctions.

[***Pace***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pace&searchmode=none) originally meant:

> late 13c., "***a step in walking***; rate of motion," from Old French pas "a
>   step, pace, trace," and directly from Latin passus, passum "a step,
>   pace, stride," noun use of past participle of pandere "***to stretch (the
>   leg***), spread out,"

[Online Etymology Dictionary]

Therefore, you use "pace" in place of speed to describe something slow and steady.

For example, you use a "[pace-maker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pacemaker)" in stead of "speed-maker" for your heart device or someone who sets the pace in a race such as marathon as it means:

> A person or animal who sets the pace at the beginning of a race,
>   sometimes in order to help a runner break a record
>
> A device for stimulating the heart muscle and regulating its
>   contractions.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

However, if you describe a car or an airplane, you don't use "pace" for its "speed".

[***Tempo***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=tempo&searchmode=none) originally meant:

> "relative speed of a piece of ***music***," 1724, from Italian tempo,
>   literally "time" (plural tempi), from Latin tempus "time, season,
>   portion of time" (see temporal). Extended (non-musical) senses by
>   1898.

[Online Etymology Dictionary]

You also use "tempo" in place of speed to describe something slow and steady as it means:

> The speed at which a passage of music is or should be played. The rate
>   or speed of motion or activity; ***pace***:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

[***Rate***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=rate&searchmode=none) originally meant:

> "estimated ***value or worth***," early 15c., from Old French rate "price,
>   value" and directly from Medieval Latin rata (pars) "fixed (amount),"
>   from Latin rata "fixed, settled," fem. past participle of reri "to
>   reckon, think" (see reason (n.)). Meaning "degree of speed" (properly
>   ratio between distance and time) is attested from 1650s. Currency
>   exchange sense first recorded 1727. First-rate, second-rate, etc. are
>   1640s, from British Navy division of ships into six classes based on
>   size and strength. Phrase at any rate originally (1610s) meant "at any
>   cost;" weakened sense of "at least" is attested by 1760.

[Online Etymology Dictionary]

[Rate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rate) is often used for "frequency" or "quantity".

> ‘the island has the lowest crime rate in the world’
>   ‘buying up sites at a rate of one a month’

It can also mean:

> "The amount of a charge or payment expressed as a percentage of
>   another amount, or as a basis of calculation: ‘you’ll find our current
>   interest rate very competitive’
>
> (rates) (In the UK) a tax on commercial land and buildings paid to a local authority; (in Northern
>   Ireland and formerly in the UK) a tax levied on private property.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

You use "economic growth rate" not "economic growth speed" when it is expressed in a percentage.

> Conclusion: The etymological roots of those four words can shed more
>   light on their different usages.

Answer (score 1):

Speed commonly refers to the *constant rate of change over a distance*. That is, it is commonly associated with movement across a distance. It is notated as the **distance over time** as in km/hr.

Rate is a description of change over time. It doesn't have to do with distance (as with speed). For example, the *flow rate* is the rate at which a liquid flows through a medium. It is used to indicate that the preceding is a measurement of work. Other examples are descent rate, heart rate (which is actually the heartbeat), etc.

Pace describes the *rate of change*; and like speed it can also describe a change in distance. However, unlike speed - pace is measured as **time over distance**; for example: 3 minutes / mile.

In addition, pace is often used to describe the relative rate of work/action. For example; "He is walking at a fast pace." or "They couldn't keep up with the pace of work".

---

Tempo is specifically the rate at which a music piece must be played. It is the only one of the four that is tied to a specific area or practice (pace, rate and speed are generic).

Tempo is measured in beats per minute; and specific rates are given their own description - mostly from Italian. For example, *Presto* means bpm between 168 and 200. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo) has a nice list of these.

In modern vernacular - tempo has been used interchangeably with pace; especially when associated with non-music related events. For example, "They opposition upped the tempo of the game".